# how to convert docker-compose.yaml to kubernetes.yaml of traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I wanna using traefik auto discovery kubernetes service.
The docker-compose.yaml is like this:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
   version: "3.3"

services:

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

And run docker-compose up -d is working,the whoami.com discoveried.

But when I convert this to kubernetes yaml,I got error with labels,
How can I write the labels on kubernetes yaml.

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.com`)" 
  -  "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Kompose](https://kompose.io/).

It will help generate some stuff for you. But specifically with Traefik you'll have to move to either the Ingress system or Traefik's custom IngressRoute system. See [this doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/) for the former and the latter is linked in the sidebar there.

Comment: It convert label to annotations:

Comment: Yes and those will have no effect on Kubernetes.

Comment: What is the best practice for using traefic auto discovery service,I did some searching and thinking ,but get nothing.

Comment: You use a Ingress system, which I linked to the docs for above. Kubernetes uses a much more full-featured networking model than Docker itself so we have a specific object abstraction for "HTTP proxy/balancer".

Comment: You can find an overall overview of the system at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/